# Reading from multiple serial ports in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, virtualbox, serial-port, arduino

I´m trying to read and record data from two USBs that are connected to separate Arduinos and they are collecting different measurements.

I´m having difficulties even reading from a single serial stream in Ubuntu

I have Ubuntu installed via Oracle VM Virtualbox. I used to use Cygwin and would simply navigate to the folder I wanted to store my txt file and write:

```
tee </dev/ttyS1 test.txt
```

to monitor and record the data stream.

If I write the same command in a random folder in Ubuntu, I get Permission Denied, even if I add sudo in front.

How can I monitor and record a single serial stream.
How can I monitor and record multiple serial streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the correct name for your serial USB

With the device unplugged enter

```
ls -la /dev/tty*
```

Now plug in the device and enter

```
ls -la /dev/tty*
```

There should be another device appear.  If it does then that's the new device

you may see something like

```
crw-rw----    root dialout  166,  0 Sept 19 12:30 ttyACM0
```

If you do the device is recognised. Note in the example above its called **ttyACM0** yours may be different.

Note the group in this case **dialout**  If your not a member of this group add your self

```
sudo useradd dialout $USER
```

You should now be able to use the serial port using the name you found above which in my case was `ttyACM0`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the redirections aren't working as you are assuming they do. This works fine:

```
sudo sh -c "tee </dev/ttyS1 test.txt"
```

Or you can login as root:

```
sudo -i
tee </dev/ttyS1 test.txt
```

Comment: Hmm, now I get a read error. It doesn't look to be recognizing my USB inputs. If I type in dmesg | grep tty I only get "...console [tty0] enabled

Comment: Also, if I try the above command, I get tee: read error: input/output error

Comment: Are you sure that ttyS1 is your usb?

Comment: According to my windows, I have COM2 and COM14. But I tried to use ttyS1, ttyS2, ttyS3,..., up to 16 but none of them worked. I don't think the Oracle VirtualBox is recognizing my USBs